# Building table from list using nearest value?

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed, grep

I have a list similar to this...

```
1ID:42
2ID:85853
Name:Chris
Age:99
Species:Monkey
Name:Bob
Age:23
Species:Fish
Name:Alex
Age:67
Species:Cat
1ID:987
2ID:775437
Name:Tiffany
Age:32
Species:Dog
1ID:777
2ID:65336
Name:Becky
Age:122
Species:Hippo
```

I want to create a table where some of the data is taken from the nearest result. This prevents me from simply replacing "\n", "Name:", etc to make my table.

This is what I want to end up with...

```
Chris 99 Monkey 42 85853
Bob 23 Fish 42 85853
Alex 67 Cat 42 85853
Tiffany 32 Dog 987 775437
Becky 122 Hippo 777 65336
```

I hope that makes sense. The last 2 columns are taken from the nearest previous 1ID and 2ID.
There could be any number of entries after the "ID" values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumptions:

- data is always formatted as presented and there is always a complete 3-tuple of name/age/species
- first field of each line is spelled/capitalized exactly as in the example (the solution is based on an exact match)

Sample data file:

```
$ cat species.dat
1ID:42
2ID:85853
Name:Chris
Age:99
Species:Monkey
Name:Bob
Age:23
Species:Fish
Name:Alex
Age:67
Species:Cat
1ID:987
2ID:775437
Name:Tiffany
Age:32
Species:Dog
1ID:777
2ID:65336
Name:Becky
Age:122
Species:Hippo
```

One `awk` solution:

```
awk -F":" '
$1 == "1ID"     { id1=$2  ; next }
$1 == "2ID"     { id2=$2  ; next }
$1 == "Name"    { name=$2 ; next }
$1 == "Age"     { age=$2  ; next }
$1 == "Species" { print name,age,$2,id1,id2 }
' species.dat
```

NOTE: The `next` clauses are optional since each line is matching on a specific value in field 1 (`$1`).

Running the above generates:

```
Chris 99 Monkey 42 85853
Bob 23 Fish 42 85853
Alex 67 Cat 42 85853
Tiffany 32 Dog 987 775437
Becky 122 Hippo 777 65336
```

Answer (score 2):

Please see if following code fits your requirements

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my($id1,$id2,$name,$age,$species);
my $ready = 0;

$~ = 'STDOUT_HEADER';
write;
$~ = 'STDOUT';

while(<DATA>) {
    $id1     = $1 if /^1ID:\s*(\d+)/;
    $id2     = $1 if /^2ID:\s*(\d+)/;
    $name    = $1 if /^Name:\s*(\w+)/;
    $age     = $1 if /^Age:\s*(\d+)/;
    $species = $1 if /^Species:\s*(\w+)/;
    $ready   = 1  if /^Species:/;           # trigger flag for output
    if( $ready ) {
        $ready = 0;
        write;
    }
}

format STDOUT_HEADER =
Name     Age Species  Id1     Id2
---------------------------------
.

format STDOUT =
@<<<<<<< @>> @<<<<<<  @>> @>>>>>>
$name, $age, $species, $id1, $id2
.

__DATA__
1ID:42
2ID:85853
Name:Chris
Age:99
Species:Monkey
Name:Bob
Age:23
Species:Fish
Name:Alex
Age:67
Species:Cat
1ID:987
2ID:775437
Name:Tiffany
Age:32
Species:Dog
1ID:777
2ID:65336
Name:Becky
Age:122
Species:Hippo
```

Output

```
Name     Age Species  Id1     Id2
---------------------------------
Chris     99 Monkey    42   85853
Bob       23 Fish      42   85853
Alex      67 Cat       42   85853
Tiffany   32 Dog      987  775437
Becky    122 Hippo    777   65336
```

Answer (score 2):

Would you try the following:

```
awk -F: '{a[$1]=$2} /^Species:/ {print a["Name"],a["Age"],a["Species"],a["1ID"],a["2ID"]}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in Perl:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fn = 'file.txt';
open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
my ($id1, $id2);
while( my $line = <$fh> ) {
    chomp $line;
    if ( $line =~ /^1ID:(\d+)/ ) {
        $id1 = $1;
    }
    elsif ( $line =~ /^2ID:(\d+)/ ) {
        $id2 = $1;
    }
    else {
        my ( $name, $age, $species ) = get_block( $fh, $line );
        say "$name $age $species $id1 $id2";
    }
}

close $fh;


sub get_value {
    my ( $line, $key ) = @_;

    my ($key2, $value) = $line =~ /^(\S+):(.*)/;
    if ( $key2 ne $key ) {
        die "Bad format";
    }
    return $value;
}

sub get_block {
    my ( $fh, $line ) = @_;

    my $name = get_value( $line, 'Name' );
    $line = <$fh>;
    my $age = get_value( $line, 'Age' );
    $line = <$fh>;
    my $species = get_value( $line, 'Species' );
    return ( $name, $age, $species );
}
```

**Output**:

```
Chris 99 Monkey 42 85853
Bob 23 Fish 42 85853
Alex 67 Cat 42 85853
Tiffany 32 Dog 987 775437
Becky 122 Hippo 777 65336
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En '/^1ID./{N;h};/^Name/{N;N;G;s/\S+://g;s/\n/ /gp}' file
```

Stow the `ID`'s in the hold space. Gather up the record in the pattern space, append the `ID`'s, remove the labels and replace the newlines by spaces.